# Complex "bump function" with continuity on boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a function holomorphic on the interior of a disk, continuous up to the boundary of the disk, vanishes on the boundary, but not on the entire disk. Does such a function exist? The maximum modulus principle doesn't immediately apply since we only have continuity on the boundary of the disk but I can't think of any examples.

An idea that just came up:

We have continuity on a compact set and therefore uniform continuity. Given a point $z$ inside the disk and $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a sufficiently large disk $D_\varepsilon$ contained inside the original disk such that $f \leq \varepsilon$ on $\partial D_\varepsilon$ and $z\in D_\varepsilon$. Thus $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude $f(z)=0$.

Would that be correct?

Comment: But the maximum modulus principle generalises to the case where we only have continuity at the boundary. So no, any holomorphic function on an open disk with boundary values $0$ vanishes identically. Your idea is one of the common arguments for that conclusion.